# Disable a device owner app from android terminal

Tags: android, shell, terminal, adb, device-owner

well, my problem is: I have an application which is set as the device owner of a device (my tablet in this case). I did it from the terminal in Ubuntu, connecting the tablet to my PC and executting this line in the adb shell:

```
dpm set-device-owner my.app.package/my.app.route.MyAdmin
```

So, I want to disable the device owner app without restoring the device, just executing a line similar to the last one. Me and my coworker have been researching for a long time and we've never found anything about this, so I would like to know if it is possible or not, and if it is, how to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DevicePolicyManager.clearDeviceOwnerApp()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#clearDeviceOwnerApp(java.lang.String)) from your device owner app.

However note that this method has been deprecated in Android Oreo, you can still use it on Oreo devices but it might be removed in future Android versions.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the following ADB shell command to remove device owner

```
adb shell dpm remove-active-admin com.example.app/.AdminReceiver
```

Disables an active admin, the admin must have declared `android:testOnly` in the application in its manifest. This will also remove device owner and profile owners